# Error:com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: Failed to process guava-21.0.jar Android 3.1 Dev Channel

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, guava, android-studio-3.0

After updating my dependency versions in **`AndroidStudio3.1`**, I started getting the following error:

```
    Information:Gradle tasks [:app:assembleDebug]
Error:com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: Failed to process C:\Users\Blabla\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.google.guava\guava\21.0\3a3d111be1be1b745edfa7d91678a12d7ed38709\guava-21.0.jar
Error:com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: Error while dexing.
Error:com.android.tools.r8.ApiLevelException: Default interface methods are only supported starting with Android N (--min-api 24): java.util.Collection com.google.common.collect.BiMap.values()
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexBuilderForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: Failed to process C:\Users\Blabla\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.google.guava\guava\21.0\3a3d111be1be1b745edfa7d91678a12d7ed38709\guava-21.0.jar
Information:BUILD FAILED in 6s
Information:4 errors
Information:0 warnings
Information:See complete output in console
```

I have already cleaned and rebuilt project. Checked my **`"multiDexEnabled true"`** and 'compile **`'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.2'`** is added.

What else can I do?

EDIT: Adding build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.blabla"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.force 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:1.3.9'
    }

}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:27.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.0.0'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.7.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.guava:guava:21.0'
    compile 'com.microsoft.azure:azure-mobile-android:3.2.0@aar'
    compile 'com.microsoft.azure:notification-hubs-android-sdk:0.4@aar'
    compile 'com.microsoft.azure:azure-notifications-handler:1.0.1@aar'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.5.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.4.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:11.4.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.4.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.4.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.4.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.7.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.4.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.4.2'
    compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.5+'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Just after posting this, I tried to go back to 'com.google.guava:guava:20.0' and it works that way. Only when I update to 21.0 it gives the error.

Comment: post your `gradle`

Comment: show your `build.gradle`

Comment: added the `build.gradle`

Comment: Guava 21.0 requires Java 8. `Guava 21.0` probably not compatible

Answer (score 99, accepted):

I had the same issue in react-native project,

the below lines worked for me,

```
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
```

Comment: This should be the correct answer. The error is related with a dependency that is on a higher version of java of the one you are trying to use. So compile your project with newest version, not the other way around and add messy configuration to your project.

Comment: I couldn't use this because I wasn't in a position where I could append this to the `compile` task because I didn't have direct access to it. [This](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/building_java_projects.html#introduction) worked for me instead.

Comment: Where in which file should this be added?

Comment: Figured it out, and it works, thanks. You make the changes here: build.gradle (Module: app) and then within the android property.

Comment: This only leads to a NullPointerException when building.

Comment: this should be the accepted answer as this solves the real poblem. changing library version than does not need java 8 is just erasing the problem

Answer (score 42):

## Update your Guava version

Guava 21 is Java 8 only.

Update your gradle to Guava version `27.0.1-android`, which is compatible with Android:

Gradle 4.6+:

```
dependencies {
  implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:27.0.1-android'
}
```

Previous Gradle versions:

```
dependencies {
  compile 'com.google.guava:guava:27.0.1-android'
}
```

Comment: That's it. But I also had to add the following to solve another error after adding your dependency:
    `android {
        configurations.all {
            resolutionStrategy.force 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:1.3.9'
        }
    }`

Comment: @Atak where did u added this ??

Comment: @Crime_Master_GoGo "android {   } " part of app build.gradle. Adding it to answer for you

Comment: thanks a alot. wasted hours with this issue. this worked fine for me :)

Answer (score 8):

I had same problem and I solved it cleaning project and rebuilding it.

In Android Studio go to **Build --> Clean Project** and after, **Build --> Rebuild Project**

Hope it helps

Comment: The same solution worked for me after upgrade Kotlin.

Answer (score 4):

I had the similar case when I switched to OkHttp 4.x. It turned out that I had to disable the method profiling in run configuration:
`Edit Configurations` -> `app` -> `Profiling` tab -> uncheck `Enable advanced profiling`. It solved my case but I cannot use profiling now on older devices.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was getting the error because I was clicking the Debug 'app' button while my build variant was set to release.  When I changed my build variant to debug, then clicked the Debug button again, the error went away.  I hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and my problem was dependency conflict.
I searched for the conflict via the gradle dependency tree:

```
gradlew app:dependencies
```

Then I excluded the module for the conflicting library (e.g `org.json:json`):

```
api ('<conflicting-library>',{
     exclude group:'org.json', module:'json'
})
```